# Is $\sqrt{a+b} \leq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$ when $a,b \geq 0 $ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: inequality

Is $\sqrt{a+b} \leq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$ when $a,b \geq 0 $ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$? I am convinced this must be true always but I can't prove it. Is this somehow related to the triangle inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's true, and it's easily proven by squaring both sides. This operation is allowed (without worrying about the direction of the inequality) because all terms are non-negative.

Answer (score 2):

Just square both sides
and see what matches on each side.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** $$2\sqrt{ab}\ge 0$$

Add $a+b$ to both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a$ and $b$ are non negative, this is equivalent to

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le |x|+|y|, $$

which has a nice geometric interpretation if you think of right triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is related to triangle inequality. If the two sides of right triangle have lengths of $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$, then hypotenuse has length $\sqrt{a+b}$. Therefore $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b} > \sqrt{a+b}$